# Unique status where x=y mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm trying make something unique in my database.

First I check all required rows `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='y'`

this gives me 10 rows (as an example). Now what I'm trying to do is `UPDATE` a field of just one of the 10 rows and disallow any further updates once the update has been executed.

For example, imagine the 10 rows are photos and the `WHERE` clause is a date. So on a certain date only 10 photos were taken. I have created a field named `fave` and I want to select just ONE of these images. Basically this is the best photo select on that date.

How do I disable all future updates from this? To prevent me from selecting more than one favourite for any given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unique index can help.
Look at a simple example.
Say we have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE photos(
  photo_id int primary key ,
  dat date not null,
  fave enum ('y')
);
```

where `fave enum ('y')` declares, that the column `fave` can have either 'y' value or NULL.

Then define an unique index on dat+fave columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX only_one_fav ON photos(  dat, fave );
```

The index does allow only one row with given combination of dat+fav, two identic rows are prohibited - however this does not apply to null.


Take a look at this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f28a8/3

```
CREATE TABLE photos(
  photo_id int primary key ,
  dat date not null,
  fave enum ('y')
);

insert into photos( photo_id, dat ) values
(1,'2013-11-02'),(2,'2013-11-02'),(3,'2013-11-02'),(4,'2013-11-02'),(5,'2013-11-02'),
(11,'2013-11-05'),(12,'2013-11-05'),(13,'2013-11-05'),(14,'2013-11-05'),(15,'2013-11-05');

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX only_one_fav ON photos(  dat, fave );

UPDATE photos SET fave = 'y' WHERE photo_id = 2;

UPDATE photos SET fave = 'y' WHERE photo_id =14;

-- UPDATE photos SET fave = 'y' WHERE photo_id = 4;
```

There are two dates, and 5 photos are taken on each date.
Try to uncommend the last UPDATE command in this demo and hit a `Build schema` button - you will get an error message - MySql wont allow for two favorite photos id: 2 + 4 on the same date: '2013-11-02'.

Comment: thanks, i think i can get my head around this so I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Every item in table should have something to differentiate it from the others.... Like an ID.

When you find the one you want to update... Just update on one unique column, or a series of columns that make it unique.